# How to create a phased Seekbar with text above start, middle, and end

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-studio, seekbar

This is exactly what i need Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use github Library, seekbar [karabaralex/android-comboseekbar](https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar)

```
<com.infteh.comboseekbar.ComboSeekBar xmlns:cbs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        cbs:myColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: this project has no dependency

Comment: check, there is sample code on link provided. take necessay code from that.

Comment: https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can also use github library https://github.com/ademar111190/android-phased-seek-bar

It is very easy to use.

Comment: Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.ademar111190:android-phased-seek-bar:0.1.1
thnaks anyway

Comment: @Haidar Do not use like `compile 'com.github.ademar111190:android-phased-seek-bar:0.1.1'` Add only library module (phased-seekbar) after downloading project. And add dependencies like `compile project(':phased-seekbar')`